# Why my non void function in C not working ? "mode" is a variable in my program and when i call the function " Inc ( mode ) " nothing happen

Tags: c, function, void

```
//increment variables between high & low limits , temp variable , m high limit 
    int Inc ( unsigned char temp , unsigned char m )
    {
      temp++ ;
      if (temp == m)
      temp = 0 ; 
      return ( temp ) ;
    }
```

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  to make a helpful [mre]. Also read [ask] and take the [tour] again please. You seem to have missed a lot...

Comment: What makes you think that it is not working? An MRE could demonstrate, but ideally you also describe what you observe and explain what is wrong about it. Mayb show the contrast of what you get and what you expect. "nothing happen" is all your description, it is however much too short and also unlikely. The shown code definitly does something. I suspect the code which you do NOT show to mislead you into thinking that nothing happens.

Comment: You have a non-void function, which returns something. At a wild gues (because you do not provide any info on it) you are ignoring the return value. Does the calling code (I recommend to show it here) do something with what gets returned?

Comment: Your shown code has a prototype with two parameters. What you describe in the title (description should go into the body by the way) has only one parameter. Described like that, the code you are describing (in contrast to the code you are showing) should not compile without errors or at least warnings. A [mre] would make things so much easier for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The `temp` parameter is a **local** variable of the `Inc` function.

You want either this:

```
 void Inc ( unsigned char *temp , unsigned char m )
 {
   (*temp)++ ;
   if ((*temp) == m)
     (*temp) = 0 ; 
 }

 ...
 mode = 1;
 Inc(&mode, 10);
 // mode is 2 now
```

or simply this using your original function:

```
 mode = 1;
 mode = Inc(mode, 10);
 // mode is 2 now
```

I guess your code looks like this:

```
 mode = 1;
 Inc(mode, 10);  // calling Inc and ignoring the return value
 // mode is still 1 now
```

Comment: You might have guessed right about the nature of the problem, but that's not at all clear.  The OP's function does return the incremented value, which affords a viable usage model different from the one your modified version requires.  The question title does specifically call out that it's a non-`void` function, after all.